# Mocha complains about done() even though it is used

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, web3js, async.js

I am writing some tests of Solidity using Mocha module. The test fails below with this error despite the fact that the done() function is called and the promise is resolved (the commented out console.log() statements show that the Promise from the included module compile.js indeed resolves).
Perhaps I'm not interpreting the error correctly? I am new to Node.js, so my apologies if I cooked up a mess.

1. "before each" hook for "Deploy a contract":

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async (done) => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  // console.log(accounts);
  
  const generate = require('../compile');
  await generate()
  .then(async data => {
    var interface = data.interface;
    var bytecode = data.bytecode;

    // console.log('ABI ' + interface);
    // console.log('BIN ' + bytecode);
    inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
            .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Greetings!']})
            .send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
  });
  done();
});

describe('Inbox testing', () => {
   it('Deploy a contract', () => {
     console.log('Contract ' + inbox);
   });
});
```

The function generate() imported from compile.js returns promise

```js
function generate() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
    })
  })
}

module.exports = generate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `mocha` might be going crazy because you need to manually close your `web3` connection after running your tests. Try calling [`disconnect`](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/b958841aa156fe3d62513dbc46679923fc4375d4/packages/web3-providers/lib/providers/AbstractSocketProvider.js#L93) after your tests run:

```
after(done => {
  web3.currentProvider.disconnect()
  done();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, it only added another odd error " TypeError: web3.currentProvider.disconnect is not a function
      at Context.done (test/inbox-test.js:48:27)"

Comment: Looking at `ganache-core` maybe you can try `web3.currentProvider.close()`. If it doesn't work either, maybe `ganache.provider().close()` ?? Lmk how it goes :) PS: updated above code to call `done()` hehe

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a `done` callback with an async function in Mocha. Also, it's not a good idea to pass an async function to `.then`. I would refactor the test function to use asynchronous style code only.

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  // console.log(accounts);

  const generate = require('../compile');
  const data = await generate();
  var interface = data.interface;
  var bytecode = data.bytecode;

  // console.log('ABI ' + interface);
  // console.log('BIN ' + bytecode);
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
          .deploy({data: bytecode, arguments: ['Greetings!']})
          .send({from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000'});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. Unfortunately the suggested refactoring did not resolve the issue - I'm still getting the same error "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves."

Comment: could you find of solution for that?